# pandas.DataFrame.from_dict not preserving order using OrderedDict

Tags: python, pandas, python-collections

I want to import OData XML datafeeds from the Dutch Bureau of Statistics (CBS) into our database. Using lxml and pandas I thought this should be straigtforward. By using OrderDict I want to preserve the order of the columns for readability, but somehow I can't get it right.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from lxml import etree
import requests
import pandas as pd


# CBS URLs
base_url = 'http://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataFeed/odata'
datasets = ['/37296ned', '/82245NED']

feed = requests.get(base_url + datasets[1] + '/TypedDataSet')
root = etree.fromstring(feed.content)

# all record entries start at tag m:properties, parse into data dict
data = []
for record in root.iter('{{{}}}properties'.format(root.nsmap['m'])):
    row = OrderedDict()
    for element in record:
        row[element.tag.split('}')[1]] = element.text
    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df.columns
```

Inspecting `data`, the OrderDict is in the right order. But looking at `df.head()` the columns have been sorted alphabetically with CAPS first?

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Something in your example seems to be inconsistent, as `data` is a `list` and no `dict`, but assuming you really have an `OrderedDict`:

Try to explicitly specify your column order when you create your DataFrame:

```
# ... all your data collection
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
```

This should give you your DataFrame with the columns ordered just in exact the way they are in the OrderedDict (via the `data.keys()` generated list)

Comment: thanks @chris-sc, this works. The `data` is a list of OrderedDicts, so in fact each item in that list is a record. Slight modification to your solution `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data[0].keys())`. Yet, a bit disappointing that it doesn't infer this automatically, but that may be just me ...

Comment: You can also go with the more concise `columns=data` since iterating over `data` iterates over the keys.

Comment: does not work for me in python 3, unless the to_html function is doing something to order, but I highly doubt that.

Comment: @user637338 you could test that easily, right? How does it look in plain python? I guess you are using ipython notebooks (therefore to_html) - Could you try that in a console and see if its still not working?

Answer (score 2):

The above answer doesn't work for me and keep giving me "ValueError: cannot use columns parameter with orient='columns'".

Later I found a solution by doing this below and worked:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict (dict_data) [list (dict_data[0].keys())]
```

Comment: I use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data).loc[list(dict_data[0].keys())]` note that the `.loc` is needed.