# Ordered dictionary from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I have the following code (Python 2.7):

```
response2 = requests.get(...)
sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response2.json())['results'].to_dict()
```

This creates a dict from my DataFrame and I'm creating a Json from it However it is not sorted:

[image]

How can I sort it by key? meaning `isGift` before `ShippingAddress_city` etc...

I saw privious answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33752819/pandas-dataframe-from-dict-not-preserving-order-using-ordereddict) but I can't manage to do it in my code...
tried also `to_dict(into=ordered)` but nothing happens.

Is there an easy way to sort it from the start? Or must I sort it only after creation and if so how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a custom key and feed into `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sample_object = pd.DataFrame(response2.json())['results'].to_dict()
sorted_object = OrderedDict(sorted(sample_object.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Note that dictionaries before Python 3.7 are considered unordered. Since `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, the above method should not cause issues with downstream operations.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: @jack, Then this answer will help, see [OrderedDict docs in 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) :). Since you are using 2.7, you can use `dict.iteritems` as per update.